# MSBuild: Compare ItemGroups or access by index

Tags: msbuild

For a C++ project, I want to autogenerate a `defs.h` file with project definitions, such as the date, git commit, ... to automate the versioning process of my application.

Therefore I am trying to create a MSBuild Target that will extract the latest git tag, git commit, and the current date and save it to a temporary `gitinfo.txt` file.
Another build target will depend on that file and generate a .h file.
In order to avoid unnecessary recompiles of my project, the .h file and for that reason the `gitinfo.txt` file shall only be rewritten, if any of the information has changes.

So my idea is the following:

1. Calculate git and date info
2. If available, read in the existing `gitinfo.txt`
3. Compare the calculated values to those in the txt file
4. If anything has changed, rewrite the `gitinfo.txt`

I've mastered steps 1. and 2., however I am not sure how to process the values after reading them.

```
<!-- The purpose of this target is to update gitinfo.txt if git information (commit...) has changed -->
<Target
  Name="GetHeaderInfos"
  BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
  Outputs="$(IntDir)\gitinfo.txt"
>

  <!-- Get information about the state of this repo-->    
  <GitDescribe>
    <Output TaskParameter="Tag" PropertyName="NewGitTag" />
    <Output TaskParameter="CommitHash" PropertyName="NewGitCommitHash" />
    <Output TaskParameter="CommitCount" PropertyName="NewGitCommitCount" />
  </GitDescribe>

  <!-- Get the current date -->
  <Time Format="dd.MM.yyyy">
    <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="NewBuildDate" />
  </Time>

  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(IntDir)\gitinfo.txt" Condition="Exists('$(IntDir)\gitinfo.txt')">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Version" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile> 

  <!-- Comparison here! HOW TO DO IT PROPERLY -->
  <PropertyGroup>
     <TagChanged> <!-- `$(NewGitTag)` == `$(Version)[0]` --> </TagChanged>
     <!-- Other comparisons -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

And this could be the content of `gitinfo.txt`

```
v4.1.4
04fe34ab
1
31.07.2016
```

I am not quite sure how to compare the values now. I need to compare `$(NewGitTag)` to the first value in the `$(Version)` version variable, and so on.

I haven't found an example, that actually accesses the variables after reading them from a file. The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms164299.aspx) provides no help, nor have I found anything on stackoverflow or the likes.

I only know that the `$(Version)` variable holds a list, and I can batch process it. How can I compare its content to the defined variables `$(NewGitTag)`, `$(NewGitCommitHash)`, `$(NewGitCommitCount)` and `$(NewBuildDate)`?

Comment: Another way: write git info and date to a file, compare those files using Exec task to invoke window's fc.exe and use it's return value to decide if the files are equal, if not copy the file. Something like here: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/windows/msvc/genhdr.targets#L94

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid way. I will try it. However, I'd really like to know how it can be achieved, also for future use cases.

Comment: Ok, see answer. And maybe edit your question/title so it's easier for future visitors to discover it: basically it's 'How to access items from an ItemGroup by index' or even just 'How to compare ItemGroups'. Also maybe make it more minimal: you just start with an ItemGroup and a bunch of items and you want to compare them. Whether those items come from a file or from GitDescribe is irrelevant, and it makes it harder to test code since not everyone has GitDescribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we start with this data:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Version Include="v4.1.4;04fe34ab;1;31.07.2016"/>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <GitTag>v4.1.4</GitTag>
  <GitSHA>04fe34ab</GitSHA>
  <Count>1</Count>
  <Date>31.07.2016</Date>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then here are *at least* 3 ways to achieve comparision (apart from the one mentioned in the comment) and there are probably other ways as well (I'll post them if I can come up with something else):

**Just compare the items**

I'm not sure why you want to compare everything seperately when this works just as well: compare the whole ItemGroup at once.

```
<Target Name="Compare1">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionChanged>True</VersionChanged>
    <VersionChanged Condition="'@(Version)' == '$(GitTag);$(GitSHA);$(Count);$(Date)'">False</VersionChanged>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="VersionChanged = $(VersionChanged)" />
</Target>
```

**Batch and check if there's one difference**

Each item of Version is compared with e.g. GitTag via batching. The result will be `False;False;False;False` if there's a difference, else it will be `True;False;False;False`. Count the distinct elements and if it's 2 it means we got the latter so GitTag did not change. Note this obviousle only works if each of your source items can never have the same value as one of the other items.

```
<Target Name="Compare2">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TagChanged>True</TagChanged>
    <TagChanged Condition="'@(Version->Contains($(GitTag))->Distinct()->Count())' == '2'">False</TagChanged>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="TagChanged = $(TagChanged)" />
</Target>
```

you can then compare the other items as well and combine the result.

**Use an inline task to access items by index**

This comes closest to what's in your question, but it does need a bit of inline code.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="IndexItemGroup" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Items Required="true" ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]"/>
    <Index Required="true" ParameterType="System.Int32"/>
    <Item Output="true" ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[Item = Items[ Index ];]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="Compare3">
  <IndexItemGroup Items="@(Version)" Index="1">
    <Output PropertyName="OldGitSHA" TaskParameter="Item"/>
  </IndexItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SHAChanged>True</SHAChanged>
    <SHAChanged Condition="'$(GitSHA)' == '$(OldGitSHA)'">False</SHAChanged>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="OldGitSHA = $(OldGitSHA), changed = $(SHAChanged)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: The first suggestion is very useful, it's the one I ended up using. About the second one, what if everything changed, then it would be `True;True;True;True` and hence it would be wrongly marked as "not changed"?
As for the third one, I didn't know it would be quite as complicated, but at least I understand how it can be used.

Comment: The second one compares only GitTag to Version, so can only return True;True;True;True if somehow Version would be equal to "v4.1.4;v4.1.4;v4.1.4;v4.1.4"